# Is there a way of implementing zero-touch enrollment onto a Buy your own device?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise, emm

I want to enroll an android device into my enterprise and I want a Factory reset-proof solution which is done by zero-touch enrollment but the thing is It says to purchase a device from an authorized re-seller and I wanted to implement it into an existing device.

Answer (score 0):

Only an authorized reseller can register a device to an enterprise for Zero Touch enrollment. This process is intended only for new devices.

This is covered in the [Android Enterprise Help](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7514005?hl=en).